# Java long Numbers Help

Tags: java, variables, numbers, int, long-integer

So at the top of my code I declared the variable
`private long counter;`
And when I try to give it a number that's really long it gives an error, Im trying to do this
`counter = 1111111111111111;`
Thats 16 "1"s and I keep getting the error "**The literal 1111111111111111 of type int is out of range**" what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this:

`counter = 1111111111111111l;`

Note that the last character there is the letter 'L' (lowercase, of course), and not the number one.  Here is a clearer example:

`counter = 2222222222222222L;`

As others have pointed out, an uppercase 'L' also works and is much more clear.  All integer literals in Java are interpreted as `ints` unless you suffix them with an 'L' (or 'l') to tell the compiler to interpret it as a `long`.

A similar thing happens with literal floating-point numbers, which are interpreted as `doubles` by default unless you suffix them with an 'f' to tell the compiler to interpret it as a `float`.  As in:

```
double num1 = 1.0;  //1.0 is treated as a literal double
float num2 = 1.0;   //1.0 is still treated as a literal double; the compiler may complain about loss of precision
float num3 = 1.0f;  //1.0 is treated as a float, and the compiler is happy
```

Comment: thats an L at the end, for the blind.

Comment: Or you could avoid any such visual issues and use uppercase `L` ;)

Comment: @Brian Roach - Thanks, I didn't even realize that Java would accept the uppercase version.

Comment: ok what if i have "long testInt = Integer.valueOf(inputBox.getText().toString());" and that number im trying to put in is a long number?

Comment: @Brendan Winter - Just use `Long.valueOf` instead, like:  long testInt = Long.valueOf(inputBox.getText().toString());`.  Otherwise your input value will either be truncated to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or (more likely) will fail to parse entirely.

Answer (score 1):

The java compiler reads any number as an integer by default.  11111111111 is obviously outside the range of an integer.  Type  `counter=11111111111L;` to get the compiler to read the value correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that numeric literals are `int`s by default.  To make the numeric literal a long you have to finish it with the alpha character `l` (lower-case L).  So:

```
long counter = 1111111111111111l;
```

In C# you can also use an upper-case L.  I'm not sure about Java.

Comment: You can use either, but IMHO `L` is preferable for visual reasons.